# Remove repeated Jars in multimodule project

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a multimodule project using Maven,Spring.what we are doing is bundling 2 war inside an ear.
so to deploy and work successfully i need to include all spring and related jars in both of the war.is there any way that i can common out those jar and put it inside a common ear's lib?i can not paste my pom fields due to security constraint

Comment: You can define a list of dependencies which will be put into a [APP-INF/lib folder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-module-location.html)

Comment: Add `<scope>provided</scope>` for common dependencies in WAR module.